# Google Drive SDK - DrEdit Python - Web Store Manifest

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been trying to work through the DrEdit python [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python) for the Google Drive SDK.  When I get to step 4, create a web store listing, I'm encountering a problem.  I [modified](https://developers.google.com/drive/listing#modify_the_listings_manifest_for_your_drive_app) the manifest.json file as described.  However, after I create the manifest.zip file, I am unable to upload the manifest archive from the web store developer dashboard.  I receive the following error message:

"An error occurred: Invalid manifest. If your manifest includes comments, please remove them as our gallery does not support them yet."

Now, if I remove the 'container' and 'api_console_project_id' entries from the manifest, it uploads fine.  However, without these entries, the DrEdit application will not be "integrated into Google Drive", correct?

I also tried to install the manifest in Google Chrome directly (developer mode). In this case, I get warnings about the two entries in question (not recognized).

How do I resolve this issue?  Is it possible that the "Setting up the sample application" documentation is out of date?

(edit)

Manifest File:

```
{
    "name" : "DrEdit",
    "version" : "1.0.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description" : "Test Google Drive application",
    "container" : "GOOGLE_DRIVE",
    "api_console_project_id" : "dpederson-gae-dredit-api",
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon-128.png"
    },
    "app" : {
        "launch" : {
            "web_url" : "https://dpederson-gae-dredit.appspot.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the manifest with your modifications

Answer (score 2):

The `api_console_project_id` field is invalid. It should match the `App ID` value from the Drive SDK tab of the APIs Console, the one you got when registering the app as explained at https://developers.google.com/drive/register

Comment: Ah, I see.  The naming convention threw me off because there is a "Project ID" on the APIs dashboard.  I saw "api_console_project_id" in the JSON manifest and assumed this value.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: for that field, it should be numbers that was assigned to Project Number in the console not the Project ID

Answer (score 0):

It should match the CLIENT_ID. More exactly the xxxxxxxx part from the xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com