# No application with id "XXXXXXXX" is installed

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

The Google Drive Share Dialog has suddenly stopped working on our app which integrates with Google Drive. Looking into it this is the message which appears when a call to `showSettingsDialog`:

[image: Frame Screenshot]

Things I've checked already:

- App is installed via the Chrome Web Store
- [App domain & URL is registered with the Google Drive SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12709893/google-drive-sdk-javascript-file-sharing-dialog-gives-refused-to-display-docume)
- [The "Drive Open URL" is the same as the page I'm calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344055/google-drive-api-cant-open-standard-sharing-dialog-via-js-x-frame-options-err) `showSettingsDialog` on.
- App is the default app on Google Drive for my file type.
- The `manifest.json` [contains the appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819042/google-drive-sdk-dredit-python-web-store-manifest) `api_console_project_id`
- [I've included the necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030374/drive-sharing-popup-wont-open) `drive.install` scope in my OAuth flow

Nothing in my project has changed, it's just recently started happening. This is my `ShareClient` code:

```
gapi.load('drive-share', function () {
    var client = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient("<API_PROJECT_ID>");
    /* Some Angular Stuff */
    drive.setItemIds(itemsArray);
    drive.showSettingsDialog();
});
```

Where `API_PROJECT_ID` is the same as the `api_console_project_id` defined in my `manifest.json`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to allow users to access Google Drive with the Drive SDK API.

This can be done via the Google Console.

Apps > G Suite > Drive and Docs > Data Access